# VENDORPATH\facebook\graph-sdk\src\Facebook\Http\GraphRawResponse.php : 108

Tags: php, api, facebook, codeigniter-4

Hola estoy intentando iniciar sesion en facebook con la api al comienzo mi app funcionaba bien luego de unos dias no movi nada y ahora cuando intento usarla solo me lanza este error estoy usando el sdk php de facebook con codeigniter 4

````
Undefined array key 1
VENDORPATH\facebook\graph-sdk\src\Facebook\Http\GraphRawResponse.php at line 108

101      * Sets the HTTP response code from a raw header.
102      *
103      * @param string $rawResponseHeader
104      */
105     public function setHttpResponseCodeFromHeader($rawResponseHeader)
106     {
107         preg_match('/HTTP\/\d(?:\.\d)?\s+(\d+)\s+/', $rawResponseHeader, $match);
108         $this->httpResponseCode = (int)$match[1];
109     }
110 
111     /**
112      * Parse the raw headers and set as an array.
113      *
114      * @param string $rawHeaders The raw headers from the response.```
en un foro vi que cambiaban esto
preg_match('|HTTP/\d\.\d\s+(\d+)\s+.*|', $rawResponseHeader, $match); // $rawResponseHeader = 'HTTP/2 200'
    $this->httpResponseCode = (int)$match[1];

por esto 

   preg_match('/HTTP\/\d(?:\.\d)?\s+(\d+)\s+/', $rawResponseHeader, $match);
        $this->httpResponseCode = (int)$match[1];
al comienzo me funciono pero no movi nada pasaron unos dias y dejo de funcionar
````